# Cannot find a full text for this ref

Tags: reference-request

I have a reference that I strongly want to read :

- Kenney, J.F., Keeping, E.S.: *The k-Statistics*. In Mathematics of Statistics. Part I, §7.9, 3rd edn. Van Nostrand, Princeton (1962)

However it's old and I did not manage to find a full text online. Could you help me?

**Edit:** I'm also interested in the second edition of part 2:

- Kenney, J. F. and Keeping, E. S. Mathematics of Statistics, Pt. 2, 2nd ed. Princeton, NJ: Van Nostrand, 1951

Comment: If it is not available on-line, try a library, such as a university library.  Even if they do not have it, they may be able to get it by inter-library loan.

Comment: It seems that Internet Archive has an *older edition* (with only Kenney listed as author): [Part 1](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.263265), [Part 2](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.263266). HathiTrust seems to have all three volumes: https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000579897 - but still the older edition and one cannot download the whole book.

Comment: In all those edditions, i did not found 'The k-statistics' chapter, the one that I am interested in. Might have been added in the third eddition... Thanks anyway @MartinSleziak for the help. I'll go ask to my local library when the pandemy is over ;)